# Slow file io performance after large network copy on Win7

Tags: windows, performance, filesystems

In a step of our build process we run a tool that generates about 125,000 files. When generation is complete we copy them up to a network share so other systems can copy them down to process further.

We see a slow down (about -300%) in performance if we have to perform the full copy of files from the network. If we already have the files locally and I reboot the system, performance is great.

My current hypothesis is that Windows has some sort of file descriptor or file handle left open and the copy is still holding on to them slowing down file system intensive tasks.

Our [monitoring charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTxi7.png) don't show much out of the ordinary and is mostly in line with a system that is performing well...it just takes longer. The slowdown is most visible in Threads where the time spent around 1500 is normally much shorter.

I should also note the 125k files are all in one directory. I know this affects performance of iterating the directory listing, but I'm not sure how it would come into play for this issue.

### System info:

- Dell R7910 Rack
- Intel 750 1.2tb PCIe
- Windows 7 Enterprise

### monitoring chart

[image: monitoring charts]

Answer (score 0):

What is the other end running? (Windows, Linux, specific NAS OS, ...) Are both ends using SMBv2 for files transfer? What is the performance on the destination server?

If nothing works, you can always try to zip the files into a single file in the origin system, transfer that file and uncompress on destination...